# What is the best way to punctuate the sentence, "The thing that makes you happy, do that."

Tags: punctuation

“The thing that makes you happy, do that.”

I feel like the comma is not perfectly correct here. Should it be a dash or a semicolon instead, or maybe an ellipsis...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good place for an [m-dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html): "The em dash is perhaps the most versatile punctuation mark. Depending on the context, the em dash can take the place of commas, parentheses, or colons—in each case to slightly different effect."

Comment: So it would look like:
The thing that makes you happy—do that.